# Updating AST in jjtree/javacc

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, javacc

I have a small c like language for which I have generated a parser and created a printVisitor using jjtree. Now, I want to be able to change the AST and print the new modified AST.

For example I have a production for a construct called "taint" which wraps definitions inside it. I want while parsing to change that AST to point directly to the declaration and ignoring the taint constructs. 
That this

```
 taint(int x)  ====becomes after parsing===> int x
```

how is that possible? I am not sure if I need a visitor for that or can I change the jjtree directly to include that.

Below is the code for the production. Your help is much appreciated.!

```
void Taint() #Taint: {Token t; String varname; }
{
  t = <TAINT>< LPAREN> varname=Primitive()< RPAREN>
  {
    ST.put(varname, new STC(varname, true, true));
    jjtThis.value=t.image;

   }
}

String Primitive() #Primitive: { String type; String name;}
{
  type=Type() name=Id()
  {
    ST.put(name, new STC(name, false, true) );
    return name;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that no node should be produced for the `Taint` production?  In that case, change `#Taint` to `#void` and remove the Java code from the production.

Comment: I know I could do that, but that was really an example so I'd learn how when I'm parsing I could return a different node than the one that should be return. The reason I need that for is because I want to rewrite the code that contains certain behaviors to something that does not. In order to rewrite I need to sometime (according to some rules) change the AST of the program. For instance, when I'm parsing the 'Taint' I could return an If statement. In that sense i've changed the code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.  I'd suggest rewriting the question to show a few example pairs of input strings and corresponding output trees.